# NodeJS form validation not returning the expected/right errors (only the last validation)

Tags: node.js

I have a simple code that contains a login form. I have enabled server side verification for the login input fields. The code is as follows:

```
const validator = require('validator')
const isEmpty = require('./util')

const validateLoginInput = (data) => {
let errors= {}

data.email = !isEmpty(data.email) ? data.email : '';
data.password = !isEmpty(data.password) ? data.password : '';

if(validator.isEmpty(data.email))
    errors.email= "Email is required"

if(validator.isEmpty(data.password))
    errors.password= "Password is required"

if(!validator.isEmail(data.email))
    errors.email= "Email Incorrrect"

return{
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors)
  }
}
```

And the api where it is used is:

```
exports.registerPatient = (req,res) =>{

const {isValid, errors} = validateRegisterPatient(req.body)

if(!isValid)
    return res.status(400).json(errors)
```

Now when i run this backend code on postman,providing only the password and not the email, I expect to get the error `"Email is required"` but unluckily i bump into the error `"Email Incorrect"`. Any fixes?

Comment: Hi @Emma, that's because your last validation overwrites the value returned by the first one. This is because an empty string "" for email matches "isEmpty" and also isEmaill. Check my answer bellow for a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Your last validation is overwriting the first one. In order to prevent this you can use:

```
const validator = require('validator')
const isEmpty = require('./util')

const validateLoginInput = (data) => {
let errors= {}

data.email = !isEmpty(data.email) ? data.email : '';
data.password = !isEmpty(data.password) ? data.password : '';

// Email validations (2 of them)
if(validator.isEmpty(data.email))
    errors.email= "Email is required"
else if(!validator.isEmail(data.email))
    errors.email= "Email Incorrrect"

// Password validations (Only 1 validation)
if(validator.isEmpty(data.password))
    errors.password= "Password is required"

return{
    errors,
    isValid: isEmpty(errors)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use double exclamation marks :

```js
let email='';
console.log(!!email);

email = null
console.log(!!email);

email = undefined ;
console.log(!!email);
```

Comment: Hey for you who decrease, ```validator``` can't determine ```undefined``` as empty. Don't decrease when you don't know.